# HTML email sending as plaintext with headers in subject

Tags: php, html-email

I am trying to send an HTML email with the PHP code below. I think that the headers are causing problems but I don't know how to fix them and googling has yielded no helpful results. Thank you!

```
$emailBody = 'Hello, Thank you for signing up for our website. Please confirm your email. <a href = "'.CONFIRM_PAGE.'&code='.$currentEmailProperties[1].'&addr='.urlencode($currentEmailProperties[0]).'&">Confirm email address</a>';
$emailBody = wordwrap($emailBody,70);
$headers = 'From: '.FROM_ADDRESS.' \r\n ';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html \r\n';
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
mail($currentEmailProperties[0],'Welcome to Our Website',$emailBody,$headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape sequences are not evaluated when used in single quotes.  Place them in double quotes, e.g.:

```
$headers = 'From: ' . FROM_ADDRESS . "\r\n";
```

From the manual:

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and
>   escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they
>   occur in single quoted strings.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Thank you very much! Out of curiosity, are double quotes the preferred way of handling strings in PHP? I always use single quotes for PHP and double quotes in the HTML, but I don't know if there's any reason to do that.

Comment: Single quotes require _slightly_ less processing time, since PHP will not have to interpolate any values, it can just pass the string right through.  However the effect is probably minimal, so unless you're processing 10,000 strings you won't notice it.  I believe double quotes for HTML attributes are generally accepted to be a best practice, but for PHP it should be whatever you feel most comfortable with.